# Windows CE Unload.exe

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce

I'm trying to uninstall a Program on my Windows CE Device. I've tried two ways but none of them worked.

My first attempt is to use unload.exe.
Problem is that i don't have Unlaod.exe in my Windows folder so i get a message that my command (unload.exe "App") cannot be executed.
What i can see in my Windows folder is a Unload_cab.exe but when i use my uninstall command (Unload_cab.exe "App") the command is executed but does nothing.

My second attempt is to use wap-provisioningdoc but again program is not uninstalled

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
<characteristic type="UnInstall">
    <characteristic type="App">
      <parm name="uninstall" value="1" />
    </characteristic>
</characteristic>
```

In my Windows Folder i can see a .tmp file that belongs to the app but i don't know if there are any info's that could help my uninstall programs.

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
<characteristic type="Install">
    <parm name="InstallPhase" value="uninstall"/>
    <parm name="SetupPath" value=""/>
    <parm name="AppName" value="FBR"/>
    <parm name="InstallDir" value="\Program Files\FBR-BDE.Setup" translation="install"/>
    <parm name="NumDirs" value="3"/>
    <parm name="NumFiles" value="12"/>
    <parm name="NumRegKeys" value="0"/>
    <parm name="NumRegVals" value="0"/>
    <parm name="NumShortcuts" value="1"/>
</characteristic>
<characteristic type="Registry" cfgnodetype="characteristic"/>
<internal-transaction type="Install"/>
<internal-transaction type="FileOperation"/>
<characteristic type="FileOperation">
    <characteristic type="\Windows\Start Menu\FBR-MES-L2.lnk" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\FBR-MES-L2.lnk" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files\FBR-BDE\Microsoft.WindowsMobile.dll" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files\FBR-BDE\Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Forms.dll" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files\FBR-BDE\NLog.dll" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files\FBR-BDE\Symbol.dll" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files\FBR-BDE\Symbol.Barcode.dll" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files\FBR-BDE\Symbol.Audio.dll" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files\FBR-BDE\SymbolScanner.dll" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files\FBR-BDE\FBR-BDE.exe" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files\FBR-BDE\config.xml" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files\FBR-BDE\plaetze.xml" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files\FBR-BDE\NLog.config" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files\FBR-BDE\DataGridColumns.dll" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="Delete"/>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="\Program Files" translation="install">
        <characteristic type="FBR-BDE" translation="install">
            <characteristic type="RemoveDir"/>
        </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
</characteristic>
```

Comment: Your CAB isnt listed in the "Remove Programs" list from the windows Control Panel?

Comment: It is listed in the Remove Programs with this name  <parm name="AppName" value="FBR"/>

Comment: Why cant you just use the Remove Programs dialog to remove the program?

Comment: Because i'm using a Management System to install it (with wceload.exe) so i would need a way to uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

The app name is missing from the XML.  See the following XML to uninstall the application named FBR.  The value you put in the second characteristic type attribute must match the name of the app as shown in Add/Remove Programs.

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
<characteristic type="UnInstall">
    <characteristic type="FBR">
      <parm name="uninstall" value="1" />
    </characteristic>
</characteristic>
```

Comment: Sorry i just used this as placeholder because i tried with different Apps, i should have made this clear in my first post